# Gurgling and sudden water through pipes noise?

Tags: plumbing, water, drain

Just about 2-3 days ago I've noticed a couple of strange things:

1. When I flush my toilet our shower drain (I believe) which is right next to the toilet makes a weird gurgling noise after the toilet is flushed
2. I have suddenly started hearing water like rushing through the pipes randomly today and yesterday.  It happens for like 2-3 minutes and then I hear what almost sounds like an explosion and the water sound goes away?  It almost is similar to the sound that is made when I first turn on my water sprinkler valve downstairs once spring time hits to get my sprinklers to go on.  Like it sounds like a huge rush of water coming fast.  But why is this suddenly happening now?

For item 1 I have tried checking the shower for hair or clogs (as I do have 3 daughters and my wife and they all have long thick hair) but I didn't find too much hair, I also used a little liquid drano.  This doesn't seem to have fixed anything.

I checked the entire house and we have not left any water on nor do I see any visible leaks inside or outside.  What gives?  Please note: for item 2 it happens randomly so far it happened early this morning around 9AM EST and again at 2PM EST.

Comment: sounds like the water is getting sucked out of the shower drain trap ... run lots of water into the shower and flush the toilet to see if there is suction ... suction could be caused by a plugged sewer vent stack

Comment: are your sprinklers going on?

Comment: @Willk i closed my sorinklers for the year i shut the valve located downstairs and will run the sprinklers out this weekend with my compressor.

Answer (score 2):

This is classic clogged vent behavior. Vents connect your plumbing to the outside air through the roof. Unless it's bird nests clogging at the roof level, the clogs are usually closer to the pipes carrying wastewater and there should be cleanout ports to allow you to access them with a snake. If there are no cleanout ports you'll need to add those.

Comment: You've made this a community wiki answer, but a little more detail would be good to get us started.

Comment: This really doesn't help me, "clogged vent behavior" what vent?  Where do I unclog it?  Where do I look?  Please explain.

Comment: @FreeMan, jsotola had already commented, so per my usual habit when a comment has been made that answers pretty much what I'm answering, it's CW. JonH, vents conect your pumbing to the outside air, so look upwards right out the roof, but unless it's bird nests, the clogs are usually closer to the pipes carrying wastewater, there should be cleanout ports to allow you to access them with a snake, if not you'll need to add those. Or DAGS on how plumbing vents work...

Answer (score 0):

In reality, a gurgling noise is one of the most easily noticeable early signs of a pipe blockage. If your drains create this gurgling noise, it is because water cannot flow freely inside the pipe. When you flush down an amount of waste water, the air in front of this water moves forward and creates a vacuum behind it. You would benefit from a good power flusher followed by a drain cleaner. Waiting any longer may end up in a complete blockage which may not be as simple as running a snake threw, a professional plumber can be costly; this is why regular maintenance is so important. Before anyone attempts repairs/maimtenance based off information they receive from the internet, it is importamt to be sure to cross reference the advice with another expert to insure best results. They may be also able to add to what was learned yo help with troubleshooting that, I in this case, your reference may not have thought of or recognized based of your description. I hope this works out for you. Best of luck-Tammy Youngman